# React Native Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

Tags: react-native

React native error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not initialize class org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BU�LD FAILED in 663ms

```
at makeError (C:\dea\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
at C:\dea\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async runOnAllDevices (C:\dea\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:94:5)
at async Command.handleAction (C:\dea\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:186:9)
```

how can i solve this problem? please help

Answer (score 0):

This issue is because of the gradle version. You can fix it by:

- First, go to `android` directory and find `build.gradle` file
- Open `build.gradle` file
- Change `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2-all.zip` to
  `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip` , using the gradle-6.3
- cmd run `react-native run-android`

Comment: It could also happen when you open the `Port 8081` without stopping the previous active one. Just run 'taskkill /F /IM node.exe' in the command line before 'npm start'